# Google Home Assistant Not Sending Requests to my Server "Agent responded empty JSON"

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-home, google-smart-home

When I am running the Test Suite, it throws all sorts of errors including "Error from HA: agentIssue" but when I pull up my server logs, there is no incoming request at all. When I checked by running a local copy (& production copy both) of the server and sent a Query/Sync request via Postman, it worked fine.

I checked the Google Logs and it says "Agent responded empty JSON" and "requestId 17169894259627458203 failed with code: GAL_NOT_FOUND". Even though my server is not registering any incoming requests. Why could this be happening?